# Qual a melhor maneira (mais rápida) de ler um arquivo de um servidor web?

Tags: java, android, web-service

Eu preciso ler um arquivo em um servidor web, mas quando preciso armazenar o conteúdo em um array de bytes está demorando muito. Alguém sabe um modo mais rápido de se fazer isso? segue meu código. Agradeço desde já.

```
try {
        url = new URL(surl);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());    
        int b = input.read();
        List<Byte> bytes = new LinkedList<Byte>();
        while (b != -1) {
            bytes.add((byte) b);
            b = in.read();
        }
        byte[] array = new byte[bytes.size()];


        //AQUI ESTÁ O PROBLEMA, ESTÁ DEMORANDO MUITO!
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i++) {
            array[i] = bytes.get(i).byteValue();
        }


        String str = new String(array);
        myreturn = str;

    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Lendo arquivos de forma rápida

No Java, existem várias classes para leitura de arquivos, com e sem *buffering*, de acesso aleatório, thread-safe, e mapeamento de memória. Algumas destas são muito mais rápidas do que outras.

### `FileInputStream` com leitura de byte

O `FileInputStream` abre um arquivo por nome ou pelo objeto `File`. O método `read()` lê byte após byte do arquivo.

`FileInputStream` usa sincronização para torná-lo thread-safe.

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(name);
int b;
long checkSum = 0L;
while ((b = f.read()) != -1) {
    checkSum += b;
}
```

### `FileInputStream` com leitura de array de byte

O `FileInputStream` faz uma operação de I/O em cada leitura e ele sincroniza em todas as chamadas de método para torná-lo thread-safe. Para reduzir essa sobrecarga, pode-se ler vários bytes de uma vez em um array de *buffer* de bytes.

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(name);
byte[] barray = new byte[SIZE];
long checkSum = 0L;
int nRead;
while ((nRead = f.read(barray, 0, SIZE)) != -1)
    for (int i = 0; i < nRead; i++) {
        checkSum += barray[i];
    }
 }
```

### `BufferedInputStream` com leitura de bytes

O `BufferedInputStream` lida com o `FileInputStream` fazendo o *buffer* por você. Ele faz o *wrap* da entrada de *stream*, cria um array de bytes interno (normalmente 8 KB), e o preenche para fazer a leitura. O método `read()` pega cada byte do *buffer*.

### `BufferedInputStream` utiliza sincronização para ser thread-safe.

```
BufferedInputStream f = new BufferedInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(name));
int b;
long checkSum = 0L;
while ((b = f.read()) != -1) {
    checkSum += b;
}
```

### `BufferedInputStream` com leitura de array de byte

`BufferedInputStream` sincroniza todos os métodos ao fazer chamadas thread-safe. Para reduzir a sincronização e *overhead* de chamadas ao método, faça menos chamadas ao método `read()` fazendo a leitura de múltiplos bytes de uma vez.

```
BufferedInputStream f = new BufferedInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(name));
byte[] barray = new byte[SIZE];
long checkSum = 0L;
int nRead;
while ((nRead = f.read(barray, 0, SIZE)) != -1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nRead; i++) {
        checkSum += barray[i];
    }
}
```

### `RandomAccessFile` com leitura de bytes

`RandomAccessFile` abre o arquivo por nome ou objeto `File`. Ele pode ler, escrever, ou ler e escrever pela posição que se escolher dentro do arquivo. O método `read()` lê o próximo byte da atual posição do arquivo.

`RandomAccessFile` é thread-safe.

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(name);
int b;
long checkSum = 0L;
while ((b = f.read()) != -1) {
    checkSum += b;
}
```

### `RandomAccessFile` com leitura de array de bytes

Tal como `FileInputStream`, `RandomAccessFile` enfrenta o problema de efetuar um operação I/O em cada acesso e sincronização em todas as chamadas a métodos para ser thread-safe. Para reduzir esse gargalo, pode-se fazer menos chamadas a métodos passando os bytes para um array e lendo a partir do array.

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(name);
byte[] barray = new byte[SIZE];
long checkSum = 0L;
int nRead;
while ((nRead = f.read(barray, 0, SIZE)) != -1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nRead; i++) {
        checkSum += barray[i];
    }
}
```

### `FileChannel` com `ByteBuffer` e busca de bytes

`FileInputStream` e `RandomAccessFile` podem retornar um `FileChannel` para operações mais baixo nível com I/O. O método `read()` do `FileChannel` preenche um `ByteBuffer` criado utilizando o método `allocate()` da classe `ByteBuffer`. O método `get()` da classe `ByteBuffer` recupera o próximo byte do *buffer*.

`FileChannel` e `ByteBuffer` não são thread-safe.

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(name);
FileChannel ch = f.getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(SIZE);
long checkSum = 0L;
int nRead;
while ((nRead = ch.read(bb)) != -1) {
    if (nRead == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    bb.position(0);
    bb.limit(nRead);
    while (bb.hasRemaining()) {
        checkSum += bb.get( );
     }
    bb.clear();
}
```

### `FileChannel` com `ByteBuffer` e busca de array de bytes

Para reduzir o gargalo da chamada de métodos de um byte de cada vez, recupere um array de bytes por vez. O array e o `ByteBuffer` podem ter tamanhos diferentes.

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(name);
FileChannel ch = f.getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(BIGSIZE);
byte[] barray = new byte[SIZE];
long checkSum = 0L;
int nRead, nGet;
while ((nRead = ch.read(bb)) != -1) {
    if (nRead == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    bb.position(0);
    bb.limit(nRead);
    while(bb.hasRemaining()) {
        nGet = Math.min(bb.remaining(), SIZE);
        bb.get(barray, 0, nGet);
        for (int i = 0; i < nGet; i++) {
            checkSum += barray[i];
        }
    }
    bb.clear( );
}
```

### `FileChannel` com array de `ByteBuffer` e acesso a array de bytes

Um `ByteBuffer` criado com o método `allocate()` usa *storage* interno para guardar os bytes. Ao invés de utilizar essa estratégia, chame o método `wrap()` para fazer um *wrap* do `ByteBuffer` envolta do seu próprio array de bytes. Isso permite que o array seja acessado diretamente após cada leitura, reduzindo o gargalo pela chamada de método e cópia de dados.

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(name);
FileChannel ch = f.getChannel();
byte[] barray = new byte[SIZE];
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(barray);
long checkSum = 0L;
int nRead;
while ((nRead = ch.read(bb)) != -1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nRead; i++) {
        checkSum += barray[i];
    }
    bb.clear();
}
```

### `FileChannel` com alocação direta de `ByteBuffer`

Um `ByteBuffer` criado com o método `allocateDirect()` pode utilizar diretamente o *storage* na JVM ou no sistema operacional da máquina. Isso pode reduzir a cópia de dados para o array do seu aplicativo, evitando alguma sobrecarga.

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(name);
FileChannel ch = f.getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(SIZE);
long checkSum = 0L;
int nRead;
while ((nRead = ch.read(bb)) != -1) {
    bb.position(0);
    bb.limit(nRead);
    while (bb.hasRemaining()) {
        checkSum += bb.get( );
    }
    bb.clear();
}
```

### `FileChannel` com alocação direta de `ByteBuffer` e busca por array de bytes

E claro, você pode recuperar arrays de bytes para reduzir a sobrecarga em chamada do método. O tamanho do *buffer* pode ser diferente do tamanho do array.

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(name);
FileChannel ch = f.getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BIGSIZE);
byte[] barray = new byte[SIZE];
long checkSum = 0L;
int nRead, nGet;
while ((nRead = ch.read(bb)) != -1) {
    if (nRead == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    bb.position(0);
    bb.limit(nRead);
    while(bb.hasRemaining()) {
        nGet = Math.min(bb.remaining(), SIZE);
        bb.get(barray, 0, nGet);
        for (int i = 0; i < nGet; i++) {
            checkSum += barray[i];
        }
    }
    bb.clear();
}
```

### `FileChannel` com `MappedByteBuffer` e recuperando com bytes

O método da classe `FileChannel`, map, pode retornar um `MappedByteBuffer` que guarda em memória parte ou todo o arquivo em espaço de memória da aplicação. Isso permite mais acesso direto ao arquivo sem um buffer intermediário. Chame o método `get()` da classe `MappedByteBuffer` para recuperar o próximo byte.

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(name);
FileChannel ch = f.getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mb = ch.map(ch.MapMode.READ_ONLY,
    0L, ch.size());
long checkSum = 0L;
while (mb.hasRemaining()) {
    checkSum += mb.get();
}
```

### `FileChannel` com `MappedByteBuffer` e leitura de array de bytes

E recuperar arrays de bytes para diminuir a sobrecarga ao método.

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(name);
FileChannel ch = f.getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mb = ch.map(ch.MapMode.READ_ONLY,
    0L, ch.size());
byte[] barray = new byte[SIZE];
long checkSum = 0L;
int nGet;
while (mb.hasRemaining()) {
    nGet = Math.min(mb.remaining(), SIZE);
    mb.get(barray, 0, nGet);
    for (int i = 0; i < nGet; i++) {
        checkSum += barray[i];
    }
}
```

### `FileReader` e `BufferedReader`

As duas classes leem caracteres ao invés de bytes. Por esse motivo precisam transformar os bytes em caracteres, levando mais tempo que qualquer uma das estratégias mostrada acima.

## Mais rápido

Se formos escolher a estratégia mais rápida, seria uma dessas:

- `FileChannel` com `MappedByteBuffer` e leitura de array de bytes.
- `FileChannel` com alocação direta de `ByteBuffer` e busca por array de bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

A maneira mais rápida depende do objetivo do programa. Se a ideia é carregar tudo em memória, basta usar um método mais eficiente.

## Lendo arquivo numa `String`

A maneira mais rápida que conheço de carregar um arquivo local para uma String em memória é tão simples quanto isso:

```
String conteudo = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("meu.txt")));
```

No entanto, isso não funciona para arquivos remotos, acessados via HTTP.

## Lendo URL numa `String`

Neste caso, o método mais rápido é continuar usando o `InputStream` e um método melhor para ler os bytes.

Conforme reportado em [outros lugares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156970/most-efficient-way-to-convert-inputstream-into-byte), a forma mais eficiente é usando o método [`sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/misc/IOUtils.java#IOUtils.readFully%28java.io.InputStream%2Cint%2Cboolean%29), assim:

```
    InputStream input = new URL("http://www.textfiles.com/humor/mel.txt").openStream();
    String conteudo = new String(IOUtils.readFully(input, -1, true));
```

### Riscos e alternativas

Claro que usar uma implementação interna de um JDK proprietário nem sempre é uma boa ideia. O método pode mudar ou deixar de existir em alguma versão futura.

A boa notícia é que é fácil substituir por uma alternativa. Uma delas é a biblioteca Apache Commons IO, cujo método [`IOUtils.toString()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) também faz o trabalho num só passo:

```
String conteudo = IOUtils.toString(input, "UTF-8");
```

A biblioteca Google Guava também faz algo parecido no método [`ByteStreama.toByteArray()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream)):

```
String conteudo = new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(input]));
```

No Java 9 não será necessário código adicional, pois a classe `InputStream` será provida com [novos métodos](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8080835) para cópia de bytes em massa.

## Considerações

Primeiro, não é preciso usar exatamente o método mais rápido, pois certamente o gargalo de desempenho acabará sendo o download do arquivo. Então, eu recomendaria usar uma biblioteca e não o método mais rápido que usa a biblioteca interna.

Segundo, a implementação atual está lenta porque está fazendo uso ineficiente dos recursos, lendo tudo numa lista e copiando tudo de novo num array e depois tudo de novo numa `String`. São pelo menos 3 vezes mais memória que o necessário.

Terceiro, muitas vezes não precisamos necessariamente carregar todo o arquivo em memória. Se logo após essa rotina você grava o conteúdo num arquivo, seria mais eficiente fazer a leitura e gravação ao mesmo tempo. Uma forma bem simples é usando a rotina [`IOUtils.copy`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)) da biblioteca Apache.

E tome cuidado com `import`s, pois várias bibliotecas tem classes chamadas `IOUtils`. Só neste exemplo vimos duas.